# Google app engine source code download

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an application created in python with google app engine, it is working fine. Now i want to make some customization in it but before uploading a particular file on the app engine i want to make a copy of that file which is deployed on server. I know a command for downloading sorce code from a app engine which is :

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>
```

but this command downloads all the source code from app engine which is not feasible for me because i want to download a single file only.

Comment: Why can't you download all the files and just pick out the one that you want?

Comment: If you have that file available locally, why can't you make a copy of it without downloading it?

Comment: Meta-comment: please re-write your post as a question, it makes it easier to parse and answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download only a single file; the choice is all or nothing.

Instead, you should use source control on your local machine. Treat source download as an emergency feature in case something goes horribly wrong, not a normal part of your development process.